# How can I delete duplicates based on two attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, duplicates

My model is really simple:

```
create_table "stack_items", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "stack_id"
  t.integer  "service_id"
  t.text     "description"
end
```

I need to remove duplicate `StackItem` records that have the same `stack_id` and `service_id`. However if one of the dupes has anything in the `description` field, I have to keep that one, and delete the other duplicate.

```
 StackItem.group(:stack_id, :service_id).order("count_id desc").where("COUNT(*) > 1")
```

So far I've tried to just grab the duplicates but it's saying I cannot count within a where statement.

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE

How can I achieve this using Rails 4 and ActiveRecord? My database is Postgresql.

Comment: Maybe StackItem.select('count(*),:stack_id,:service_id).group(:stack_id, :service_id)